# Django celery CPU uses and SIGNKLILL error

Tags: django, djcelery

Hello All i am reciving below error. i have checked status of rabbitmqctl and its working good. but find below issue when run task in periodic. Also CPU consumption increase to 100%. please help me out of this issue.

```
[2015-04-27 15:03:56,927: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tarjeta.tasks.demon_2[4d6cb246-cf34-4f70-a5a5-d56677287041] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1169, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
```

Also can you please let me kow "are there both issue related with each other ??"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is missing full traceback and related source code.